# That of Tokyo vs. one of Tokyo?

Tags: pronouns, comparatives

> - The climate of Sapporo is colder than one of Tokyo.
> - The climate of Sapporo is colder than that of Tokyo.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

**That of** is the proper comparative term in this case.

You don't speak of the climate of a locale as being a quantifiable thing.  Hence, you would not use one.  If you substitute *two* or *three* for *one*, you will see the break down of the sentence.

Otherwise, if not meant as a numerable item, the context would imply that "the climate of Sapporo is colder than *a person* [*i.e.* one] from Tokyo.  This is clearly incorrect, too.